# Kubuntu : when i move mouse, screen move too?

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, screen

I have activated some feature by fault, and I can't find how to reset the normal configuration.
the problem is when I move the mouse, the screen is already zoomed, and move too
I'm under Kubuntu

any idea

Thanks

Comment: In KDE, the shortcut to reset zoom may be disabled by default. Try to zoom out by using this combination keys: `Super`+`-` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: no, even I restart the system, always the same problem !!

Comment: Try restoring defaults.In `System Settings > Workspace > Desktop Behavior > Desktop Effects`, click on `Defaults`.

Comment: @DKBose , thank you so much :) 
finally, I get a solution

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the default on my version of ubuntu does a desktop zoom if you hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Scroll-wheel</kbd> in. For me the problem was fixed by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll-wheel</kbd> out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a laptop and for some reason the answer provided by @jjhiggz does not work, try holding down 'alt' and do zoom out/zoom in gestures on your touchpad.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1171442)